# Is there a way of delaying setting the textcolor and the background color of the content of a box until that box is used or shipped out?

Tags: color, boxes

Is there a way of delaying setting the textcolor and the background color of the content of a box until that box is used?
Is there a way of delaying setting the textcolor and the background color of the content of a box until that box is shipped out to .pdf-file or .dvi-file?

S.th. like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newbox\mytempbox
\begin{document}
\savebox\mytempbox{%
  \vbox{%
    <Some special with placeholders for values of textcolor and backgroudcolor>
    \hbox{One}\hbox{Two}%
  }%
}

<Some directive for assigning values to placeholders for values of textcolor and backgroudcolor>
\usebox\mytempbox

<Some directive for assigning values to placeholders for values of textcolor and backgroudcolor>
\usebox\mytemphbox

<Some directive for assigning values to placeholders for values of textcolor and backgroudcolor>
\usebox\mytemphbox

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you need to use `\savebox` and can't just use a command?

Comment: @JasperHabicht That's not the question. The question is not what is possible on the processing level of expansion but what is possible on the processimg level of putting boxes together as is done, e.g., by the output routine. E.g., multi-layer pdf where the output routine makes each page two layers atop each other and where the box holding the page is already created..

Comment: @Cattleya I think this depends on the output format. Probably via `\special`s or the like it is possible to bring instructions into the outut-file (dvi / pdf / postscript) for declaring some sort  of variables there, setting their values and changing the colors according to these values. But I never delved sufficiently into the pdf-format or the .dvi-format to know for sure. In postscript it shoulf be possible.

Comment: The answer is yes, but actual coding is above my head. The `lua-typo` package (lualatex only) does that, using lua to inspect the contents of a page before shipout, then coloring problem text, finally shipout with color.